# Kotlin 1.5.2 data class hashcode( ) generated implementation will result in nullPointerExeption

Tags: android, kotlin, hashcode

First, while Gson converting json string to Kt data class, Gson maybe use 'UnSafe' create data class, and assign 'null' for a NoNull field. And when this object's hashcode() being invoked, a nullPointerException is thrown.

Cause the generated bytecode by kt compiler doesn't check every field, has anybody met this issue yet?

Below shows the generated hashcode by 1.5.20 kt-compiler.

```
 public int hashCode() {
    result = this.eventId.hashCode();
    return result * 31 + this.voteId.hashCode();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Kotlin data classes can have nulls in non-nullable fields with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837665/why-kotlin-data-classes-can-have-nulls-in-non-nullable-fields-with-gson)

Comment: @a_local_nobody  No, I  know why null fields happed, I'm thinking kotlin data class hashcode implementation is somewhat weird.

Comment: then you should make your question clearer to show specifically what you're asking, at the moment i don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd thing to take issue with! To understand the generated `hashCode()` method, take a look at the pseudocode explanation at: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-does-kotlin-implement-equals-and-hashcode/940/2

The problem you're encountering is that when Gson creates and object with a null field, you've already promised the compiler that it will *not* be null so it doesn't try to catch this case in `hashCode()`.

Comment: Yes，but the kt compiler below 1.5 does have the null-check in hashcode's implementation，v1.5 removes the check because of the above consideration. It may cause some runtime NPEs when you upgrade kt version from 1.4x to 1.5